# RegEx replace characters

Tags: javascript

I want to replace all character within the brackets:

```
 var pattern = " [,°.^?]";
 let latitude = [];
 var test = "50°', 12", 212";
 latitude = string.replace(pattern, " ").split(" ");
```

But I am getting always the values with characters. It is not replacing.
Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define pattern as a regular expression literal, string is undefined in your code (that should be test) and test string should have backslash character '\"'.

```js
var pattern = /[,°.^?]/g;
let latitude = [];
var test = "50°', 12\", 212";
latitude = test.replace(pattern, " ");
console.log(latitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define pattern correctly with global flag and remove an extra " from your test string.

```js
var pattern = new RegExp("[,°.^?]", 'g');
 let latitude = [];
 var test = "50°', 12, 212";
 latitude = test.replace(pattern, " ");
console.log(latitude);
```

Comment: Maybe prefer use `"50°', 12\", 212"`, to be exactly the same as it seems Mogli needs

Comment: What is the point of using `new RegExp` instead of a regexp literal?

Comment: @NathaëlNoguès don't know if OP really wants that.

Comment: @torazaburo it is always more understandable to me, is the literal preferred over pattern for some reason?

Comment: @torazaburo It allows to generate Regexp with variables containing the regex as a String; but yeah in the case that the regex is a constant, literal is less verbose

Comment: The OP presumably wants something that works and conforms to best practices, which is a regexp literal. I'm puzzled why you think a RegExp constructor would be more understandable. It's not necessary, and also marginally less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The first parameter, when given as a string, is described as:

> substr (pattern)
>   A String that is to be replaced by `newSubStr`. **It is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression**. Only the first occurrence will be replaced.

To make your code work, write:

```
const pattern = /[,°.^?]/g;
```